# Weighted random: roll dice 1 to 1000, averages to 100... which std::distribution to use?

Tags: c++, math, random, distribution, weighted

I want to roll a dice from 1 to 1000. However, over many trials, I want the average to be 100.

How?

```
int weighted_rand(int min, int max, int avg);

...

weighted_rand(1, 1000, 100);
```

This isn't homework btw.

Uniform distributions
uniform_int_distribution
(C++11)
uniform_real_distribution
(C++11)
generate_canonical
(C++11)
Bernoulli distributions
bernoulli_distribution
(C++11)
binomial_distribution
(C++11)
negative_binomial_distribution
(C++11)
geometric_distribution
(C++11)
Poisson distributions
poisson_distribution
(C++11)
exponential_distribution
(C++11)
gamma_distribution
(C++11)
weibull_distribution
(C++11)
extreme_value_distribution
(C++11)
Normal distributions
normal_distribution
(C++11)
lognormal_distribution
(C++11)
chi_squared_distribution
(C++11)
cauchy_distribution
(C++11)
fisher_f_distribution
(C++11)
student_t_distribution
(C++11)
Sampling distributions
discrete_distribution
(C++11)
piecewise_constant_distribution
(C++11)
piecewise_linear_distribution
(C++11)

Comment: Choose appropriate distribution.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I know about std::uniform_int_distribution, but there are so many other distributions and I don't come from a math background so I do not know which one to use for this purpose.

Comment: " I want the average to be 100." - why?

Comment: Um, because that's what I need? It's irrelevant and implementation specific.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to carry out. The average is computed as the sum of elements divided by their number. This is a random experiment with a common assumption that its distribution is uniform which has a formula for its expected value.

Comment: You can have uniform distribution from 2-1000 and adjust the probability with case 1. Is it acceptable ?

Comment: @Jarod42, a die has solely six outcomes (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5, and 6).

Comment: "Um, because that's what I need?" - point is, there may be a better solution to your problem than the one you propose - XY problem anyone?

Comment: @CroCo: As I understand, OP want to roll a unfair D1000 instead of a regular D6. (which indeed is not a common dice).

Comment: Give 100 weight 1 and all the rest weight 0.

Comment: A “random” function which always returns 100 would satisfy the constraints for range and average. As would a function which returns 1 in 80% of the cases, 370 in 16% of the cases and 1000 in 4% of the cases. So I *assume* you have some additional expectations for your distribution, but you need to make them explicit to get a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to use a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mean) if its properties satisfy your needs. It gives you control over the maximum value and the mean. You can even choose a non-integer mean if you want to. You cannot choose the minimum, as that is always zero, so you may have to offset the result:

```
int weighted_rand(int min, int max, double avg) {
  std::binomial_distribution distribution{
    max - min,                // number of trials
    (avg - min) / (max - min) // success probability of each trial
  };
  return distribution(prng) + min;
}
```

Since a normal distribution is often used for continuous variables in the absence of more detailed information, using the binomial distribution as its discrete counterpart might be be a good solution.

But this is far from the only one, and depending on your use case, it might be terrible. You need to provide more details. As I wrote in a comment, a “random” function which always returns 100 would satisfy the constraints for range and average. As would a function which returns 1 in 80% of the cases, 370 in 16% of the cases and 1000 in 4% of the cases. So I assume you have some additional expectations for your distribution, but you need to make them explicit to get a suitable answer. The above assumes a kind of bell-shaped distribution.